# VB.net Programmably drop down the DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, datetimepicker, sendmessage

Hey all i have this code here:

```
Call SendMessage(dtPicker.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, True, 0&)
```

That works fine on comboboxes but doesn't seem to work when it comes to the DateTimePicker box.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that's for a ComboBox.  The native DTP control is quite noddy.  It supports the DTM_CLOSEMONTHCAL message to close the calendar but doesn't have a corresponding message to open it.  You'll have to do something ugly like faking mouse or keyboard input.  The latter is probably best:

```
Private Sub ShowMonthCalendar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShowMonthCalendar.Click
    DateTimePicker1.Focus()
    SendKeys.Send("{F4}")
End Sub
```