# SendKeys.Send NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, sendkeys

I am trying to send keys to a control on my form. But I am getting a NullReferenceException and I don't know why. The code is about as basic as it gets:

```
Private Sub Button19_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button19.Click
    DateTimePicker2.Focus() 'commenting out this line has no effect
    SendKeys.Send("{F4}") 'error thrown on this line
End Sub
```

The error reported is `object reference not set to an instance of an object` but `Send` is a shared method so doesn't need an instance.

Strangely if I ignore the error it works fine and F4 is passed to the control. I know there was an issue with sendkeys and UAC but I thought this had been solved (I am using 4.0 framework)

Comment: Is it possible that the error originates on the receiving end of the sendkey? I mean, do you have any code in your destination control that processes the F4 key?

Comment: No I don't the DatTimePicker should be processing the F4 key to show the calendar picker a la [this answer on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597880/vb-net-programmably-drop-down-the-datetimepicker/5598216#5598216)

Comment: "Strangely if I ignore the error it works fine" -- are you only getting the error in Visual Studio? Have you enabled first-chance exception notifications?

Comment: Can you give the focus to the control on the form and hit F4 to see what happens?

Comment: @JeffO - tabbing to the control and pressing F4 works ok - no error and the calendar drops down ok

Comment: @hvd - yes I am breaking on thrown exceptions, but why am I getting this exception being thrown in the first place

Comment: [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) is probably the wrong method to use: "Focus  is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wt11hea.aspx) method"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That call is not throwing an exception, the exception is thrown in the SendKeys.LoadSendMethodFromConfig() and is handled internally (so if you were to put a try/catch around that call you would see no exception is actually caught in your user code).

You're seeing it in the debugger because you have your exceptions set to break on any exception thrown, regardless of where it occurs or if it has been handled.

I suggest going to Tools > Options > Debugging and check the box next to "Enable Just My Code".

Here's what the method throwing the exception looks like. Note that it is swallowing all exceptions on purpose:

```
    private static void LoadSendMethodFromConfig()
    { 
        if (!sendMethod.HasValue) 
        {
            sendMethod = SendMethodTypes.Default; 

            try
            {
                // read SendKeys value from config file, not case sensitive 
                string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SendKeys");

                if (value.Equals("JournalHook", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                    sendMethod = SendMethodTypes.JournalHook;
                else if (value.Equals("SendInput", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                    sendMethod = SendMethodTypes.SendInput;
            }
            catch {} // ignore any exceptions to keep existing SendKeys behavior
        } 
    }
```