# Open the calendar of datetimepicker on select of Date in other datetimepicker winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have 3 Datetime pickers on a windows form in C#. The datetimepickers are named dtp1,dtp2,dtp3. Once I select a date in dtp1 I want the calendar of dtp2 to open. In other words dtp2 calendar should show up. I have searched in this forum and google but couldnt find right solution for this.

I am currently opening the calendar of dtp1 on value change of a combobox using the code  below.

```
dtp1.Select();
SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
```

But if I use the same code on Value changed event of `dtp1` it reopens the calendar of `dtp1` instead of `dtp2`. I tried the following in value changed event of `dtp1`.

```
    private void dtp1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        listView2.Items.Clear();

        dtp2.Select(); //dtp2.Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
    }
```

My intention in opening the next calendar is to force the user to select the value from the next control. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post here all of your related code, including the event handling. You obviously have a bug there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net Programmably drop down the DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597880/vb-net-programmably-drop-down-the-datetimepicker)

Comment: Use Focus() instead of Select().

Comment: Though this does look like it might be promising: http://techforpassion.blogspot.com/2011/04/howto-force-calendar-dropdown-in-net.html?m=1

Comment: @HansPassant Tried that still no luck.

Comment: @Yarimi : Posted the event handler code.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Tried the solution in VB.net Programmably drop down the DateTimePicker, its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ValueChanged event, use CloseUp

```
private void dtp1_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dtp2.Select();
    SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
}
```

Hope it helps!