# How to open datetimepicker calender with keypress event?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to open the calendar of datetimepicker control using key press event. I have try [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f2f0b213-d57a-46de-b924-e21b7ac0882e/programmatically-open-the-calendar-of-the-datetimepicker-control?forum=winforms), but the calendar disappear after the key is released. It works for ComboBox but not for datetimepicker, any ideas? The code that I write is look like this:

```
private void textBoxt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
   {
          datetimepicker1.Focus();
          datetimepicker1.Select();
          SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
    }
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to show your code for people to work out why it didnt work for you

Comment: @BugFinder I have shown my code. Please tell me if you have any idea.

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.8 ? are you just copying or have you tried other things, for example if like Ahmed suggests using ctrl+down, did you try that instesd of alt?

Comment: @BugFinder I've tried ctrl+down and it's not showing the calendar, it's backing down the year to 2018.

Comment: OK so you need to work out the keycombo, I would also suggest if possible not to use keypress but either keydown (at worst up) and then cancel any further processing by using the cancel from the eventargs..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598216/17034

Answer (score 0):

the KeyDown doesn't work with the DatePicker, use CTRL-DOWN, which will do exactly what you want.
Let me know

Comment: Do you mean like shortcut key?